# How do I plot a series of disks in the center of each hexagon?

Tags: graphics

I am trying to put a series of disks at the center of each hexagon, but I could center only 1. 
How do I center all of the disks at the center of each hexagon?

Here is the code I am using.

```
h[x_, y_] := Polygon[Table[{Cos[2 Pi k/6] + x, Sin[2 Pi k/6] + y}, {k, 6}]]
p1 = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Opacity[.7]], White, Table[h[3 i + 3 ((-1)^j + 1)/4, Sqrt[3]/2 j], {i, 0, 1}, {j, 0,3}]}];
Show[p1, Table[Graphics[Disk[{i, j}, {0.25, 0.25}]], {i, 0, 2, 1.5}, {j, 0, 2, 1.5}]]
```

Here is my result:

[image]

Comment: I do this might seem trite and still, wouldn't the solution have been more obvious if you'd thought about "How to plot a disk in the center of each hexagon?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just reuse the expression for the x and y components that you used when centering the hexagons:

```
Table[
 Graphics[Disk[{3 i + 3 ((-1)^j + 1)/4, Sqrt[3]/2 j}, {0.25, 0.25}]],
 {i, 0, 1},
 {j, 0, 3}
 ]
```

This gives you:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

You can use [`CirclePoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CirclePoints.html) to define the [`Polygon`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon.html)

```
h[x_, y_] := Polygon[{x, y} + # & /@ CirclePoints[6]]
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out in the comment by J.M., using [`RegularPolygon`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegularPolygon.html) this can be simplified to

```
h[x_, y_] := RegularPolygon[{x, y}, 1, 6]
```

The common center points are

```
ctrs = Table[
    {3 i + 3 ((-1)^j + 1)/4, Sqrt[3]/2 j},
    {i, 0, 1}, {j, 0, 3}] //
   Flatten[#, 1] &;
```

[`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) `Polygon` and [`Disk`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Disk.html) onto the centers.

```
Graphics[{
  EdgeForm[Opacity[.7]], {
     White, h @@ #,
     Black, Disk[#, 0.25]} & /@
   ctrs}]
```

[image]

Comment: Of course, your `h[x, y]` is the same as `RegularPolygon[{x, y}, 1, 6]`.

Answer (score 3):

**1.** You can post-process your `p1` to add disks at [`RegionCentroid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionCentroid.html) of polygons:

```
p1 /. p_Polygon:> {p, FaceForm[Black], Disk[RegionCentroid @ p, {1, 1} / 4]}
```

[image]

**2.** Alternatively, you can create a single disk/hexagon pair centered at `{0, 0}`

```
prims = {Black, Scale[Disk[], {1, 1}/4], 
   EdgeForm[Gray], FaceForm[], RegularPolygon[{0, 0}, 1, 6]};
```

and [`Translate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Translate.html) it using `centers`:

```
centers = {3 # + 3 (1 + (-1)^#2)/4, Sqrt[3] #2/2} & @@@ 
   Tuples[{{0, 1}, Range[0, 3]}];


Graphics[Translate[prims, #] & /@ centers]
```

[image]